# Regularization: How do you penalize weights of some exact value?

Tags: regularization, weighted-regression

Assume we have a loss function of the form:
L(f(X; theta),T) where X is the input dataset and T is the target dataset?

Then you would update the the paramters by doing
p = p - p.grad
where p.grad is the gradient achieved through gradient descent (not important here)

then I understand that L2 norm is a method of regularisation used to penalize large weights.

~L = L(f(X;theta),T) + (lambda/2) * (frobenius norm)

consequently, p = p - lr * p.grad - lambda * p

But what if I want to discourage weights of some exact magnitude. What If I want to penalize weights that are near +-0.75 more than others? Is that possible? How would the new loss function look like?

edit: Could I simply make a function of theta that increases as theta approaches 1? then that would magnify lambda (the scaling factor of the penalty) for values near 1.

Comment: you can used whatever regularization term you want. just choose a function that is large where you want it to be

Comment: but what if the loss function the model uses is predefined and cant be changed. Then what I can do is update p such that my new constraint of penalizing weights near 0.75 occurs. So I want to influence p every epoch in addition to just updating it with its gradient. How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to use gradient descent (GD), you have to change your loss function as @J.Delaney said. What you are suggesting here is changing the method of gradient descent. You could, of course, try this but you would have to make sure that your new optimization method, that replaces GD, is still actually optimizing the parameters theta in some more or less satisfying way. This is not that easy. The best bet is to change your regularization. Maybe you should explain more why you have to penalize a special theta and also why you cannot change the regularization. Maybe there are workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I can think of is adding a function of $\theta$ that tends to infinity to the lost function. For example, $\frac{1}{\theta+1}+\frac{1}{\theta-1}$ would be a good choice. For your example, swap 1 with 0.75

This is an interesting question.

If anyone knows a much better solution, let me know.